# Generic GET web api endpoint for System.Type and Id

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I'm using web api in net 7. Is there any way to make the binding engine understand a `Type` and an `object` id parameter?

I have an endpoint that I want to reuse to get an entity of a certain type by id.

AFAIK generic types are not supported in an action, so I guess what I need is something like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public object Get(Type type, object id) 
{
    // call _entityFrameWorkDatabaseContext.Find(Type type, object id)
}
```

I would like to invoke it using something like `/theAction/1?type=<AssemblyQualifiedName>`. Is it possible?

Comment: I think it is possible. You will need a custom binder for `Type`. Then, take in a string parameter and use reflection to map it to the correct type.

Comment: @beautifulcoder Alright, could you link me to the docs for a custom binder?

Comment: Sure thing! I have put sample code together to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom model binder should be able to get you what you need.

```cs
public class TypeEntityBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Treat it like a string request parameter
        if (!string.TryParse(value, out var type))
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(
                modelName, "Type must be a string.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // In a debugging session, make sure the `type` is binding correctly

        // Make sure the assembly name is correct and matches a real type
        var model = Type.GetType($"namespace.{type}, assemblyName");
        // Bind the result to Type
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;  // <-- run for the hills!
    }
}
```

Then, simply slap the attribute to active the custom binder.

```cs
Get([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(TypeEntityBinder))] Type type, object id)
```

Keep in mind, this is mostly theoretical code. One snag you could run into is the custom binder does not register properly in the request pipeline, so make sure it is actually included. Also, check the contents of the `type` variable via debugging techniques.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by getting the type as a string and using reflection to get the object Type, you can read more about reflections [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/#reflection-overview).

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public object Get(string type, int id) 
    {
        var type = Type.GetType($"namespace.{type}, assemblyName");
    
        // you can add a validator here to make sure that type is valid.
        if(type == null)
        {
            // your code goes here
        }

        // here you retrieve the data from DB using ef.
        var entity = _entityFrameWorkDatabaseContext.Find(type, id);
        
        // you can check if the entity is null and do what you want
        if(entity == null)
        {
            // your code goes here
        }

       return entity;
    }
```

1. try get the entity using reflections.
2. if getting the entity type succeded call your `_entityFrameWorkDatabaseContext` with type and Id (int/string/etc..)
3. return the entity.

you can call the endpoint in the following way

```
GET <address>/{id}?type=<your-type>
```